# Android List View with Image and about 10 strings

Tags: android, android-listview

I am planning on having an app with Image followed by Text like so:

[End state list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARiJi.png)

At this state, I should mention I am new to Java and Android.

All the details, including the URL of the image is stored in mysql, the php to retrieve the mysql records and showing them in Android is done (JSON Array)

Here is my problem. Android studio forces me to have the async operations to get details from mysql (networking), so I have to get all the details in one background function, including converting the image path stored as a Bitmap. The only option as I see is to return a list object from the backgroundjob to the main view. I need some help with the list and perhaps custom adapter to have a ImageView and 10 other strings. What I have done so far:

Php code:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","","mydb");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result=array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM temp limit 1";
$query_exec = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_exec)) {
    $row['Image']='/Images/Myimage/2/BourneIdentity.jpg';
    $result[] = $row;
}

$json_result = json_encode($result);

echo $json_result;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Please note: I have hard coded the image location for testing, I will get all the images in the folder like so:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        echo '<br>';
        $tempArray = $row;
        $dh = opendir('c:/wamp/www/'.$row->pic_dir);
        while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
            if ($filename !="." and $filename != "..") {
                echo '<img src="' .$row->pic_dir.$filename.'" width="40" height="40"/>' ;
            }
        }
        echo  '<a href="'.'test.php'.'">' . $row->description .'</a>';
    }
}
```

Android - MainActivity.java (It's not anywhere near complete, just didn't know how to go from here with list/array having to contain different objects)

```
package com.example.rgopalkr.readdb;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.lang.String;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Bitmap>
    {
        protected void onPreExecute (){
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textv);
            tv.setText("Get Discription from database");

        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
            StringBuilder str= new StringBuilder();
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/shareit/php/test_json.php");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
                str.append(conn.getResponseCode());
                conn.disconnect();
            }  catch (IOException M) {M.printStackTrace();}

            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str.toString());
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String imagePath="http://10.0.2.2/shareit/";
                for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    try {
                        JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        imagePath += oneObject.getString("Image");
                        URL bmpurl = new URL(imagePath);
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bmpurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
//                        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        sb.append(imagePath + ',');
                    } catch (JSONException | IOException e ) {e.printStackTrace();}
                }
 //               tv.setText(sb.toString());
            } catch (JSONException JE) {JE.printStackTrace();}
            return bmp;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...a){

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textv);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            iv.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

     public void loadItems(View v){
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tButton);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textv);
        new TestAsync().execute();

    }
    public void Messagebox(int msg) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

The activity main XML code, I think I know what I have change in the XML file for list view, I was playing around with different views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press to Load"
        android:onClick="loadItems"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="This is where the text will come"
        android:layout_centerVertical="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lending"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

How the emulator looks now (newbie, sorry cant embed the images yet, have to get 10 reps to embed the pics)

[How my current emulator screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR6HW.png)

I read the post here, which gave me some ideas: http-w]w[w\androidhive\info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/, but looks way complicated. If anyone can help me with the multiple object types list and give some pointers how to go forward it'll be awesome!

Also, the first screen will only have thumbnails with description, when pressed on it, all the images stored for that record should be shows.

Comment: I'm in a similar position to you. If your question concerns the listview, have you tried a custom array adapter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793999/android-listview-with-2-textviews-per-item

Comment: @ScriptKitty ListView is the old way. RecyclerView is the new way for creating a list. I used this doc to create a RecyclerView https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: @GKproggy, RecyclerView as I understand is how you display the data after you have loaded, my question is more how to load the data, but thanks for your suggestion. I'll use RecyclerView when I have all the data to show

Answer (score 0):

First thing is don't create all the bitmaps as part of the json parsing. Images that appear in a listview should be lazy loaded.

This Means all you need to do is parse the url of the image back to the UI thread.

As the user scrolls the images will be loaded at this point.

Take a look at a library called Picasso that will do the loading for you.

In your gradle file under dependencies add

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Then in getView of the listview adapter add

```
Picasso.with(context).load([imageUri]).into(imageView);
```

You can also add a place holder if you wish with

```
Picasso.with(context).load([imageUri]).placeholder([placeholder res]).into(imageView);
```

Full code for a base adapter

[How to inflate views programmatically in vertical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882564/how-to-inflate-views-programmatically-in-vertical-order/30883879#30883879)

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a try and update back how it goes. Would you have sample code please? Coming from Python, Java seems like writing a book with so many lines and files :(

Comment: It worked great! I can now fetch all the columns including URL and use Picasso to load the image from URL. I need a way to load all the rows in a list and display as scroll-able

Comment: Take a look at the link at the bottom of my answer for how to use a listview